# How to fit a table to the header maximun height?

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am developing a cordova application and I am experiencing a problem with the style of the data-role:header div. I want the header to take a maximum size of the 10% of the screen. I am able to do that but not to fit the table I have inside the div. It exceeds the size of the div as you can see in the next image:

[image]

As you can see, I have used border of the table to see the space that the tables takes, the html code is the next below:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="background-color:#1e0354; max-height:8%;">
    <table style="width:100%; margin-top:0px ;margin-bottom:0px; max-height:8%; border: 3px solid white;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;width:33%;max-height:4%;vertical-align:middle;">
              <a href="#frontPage" id="hiddenForHeight" style="visibility: none; margin-left:3px;">
                <img src="img/SaioaItxi.png" width="20%" height="8%">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center;width:33%;max-height:4%;">
              <h4 style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;white-space: nowrap;overflow: visible; color:white; ">Orrialde printzipala</h4>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the solution of this? I don't understand why the table is being so big when the elements inside it are smaller...

Comment: Possibly your css breaks with that space between the colon `margin-top:0px ;`

Comment: another thing to add which is half off topic: dont sue a table to style it. Its not only otudated but also more complicated then using flexboxes or css-grid.